# Как исправить нечёткость спрайтов

Tags: unity3d, графика, спрайт

Пользуюсь Unity 2021 и сегодня запустил игру на телефоне. Камера от игрока находится на очень маленьком расстоянии, но при этом спрайты игрока очень нечёткие. Подскажите, как это исправить. Фото стандартных настроек спрайта оставил на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото с телефона:
[image: Скриншот персонажа]

Буду очень рад помощи. За ранее спасибо и извините

Comment: Я ничего про это не знаю, но что если в `Compression` побольше качество поставить попробовать? )

Comment: @CrazyElf к сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно использовать исходное изображение, без применения фильтрации, то измените в `Import Settings` вашего изображения параметр `Filter Mode` на `Point (no filter)`.